# C# Error: The name 'RegisterHyperLink' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been working on a group project with this code that another group member wrote and I'm getting the following error:

The name 'RegisterHyperLink' does not exist in the current context

Here's the chunk of code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "Register.aspx?ReturnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
}
```

Anyone have any ideas as to why I'm encountering this error?

Comment: Have you had a look in the markup if an actual control with an id of "RegisterHyperLink" exists?

Answer (score 1):

Check your using's and your references. Sometimes people will link to a project outside the solution and the reference gets lost if the project changes place.